# Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on WIndows 2012 R2 ADFS and WAP

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs

We have ADFS and WAP environment for publishing internal Urls on which we want to disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 as the browsers will stop accepting TLS1.0 from next year July.
As per my understanding and reading the articles/blogs from microsoft/other sites, we need to add registry entries to disable tls 1.0 and 1.1.

Are there any steps which I am missing or is there something else that needs to be checked before disabling TLS.

Note: I have a very limited knowledge of Windows and am not a Windows Admin.
Any help would be appreciated.

Environment details: 
OS --> Windows Server 2012 R2
ADFS Version --> 3.0 (version 6.3 since its an OS component) 
WAP version --> WAP is a role service of the Remote Access server role in Windows Server 2012 R2
.NET Framework Version --> 3.5 and 4.5 are installed

Let me know if any additional details are required.

Thanks. 
John

Links related to TLS which I have consulted: 
Solving the TLS problem ==> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55266
Managing SSL/TLS Protocols and Cipher Suites for AD FS ==> 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/manage-ssl-protocols-in-ad-fs 
How to restrict the use of certain cryptographic algorithms and protocols in Schannel.dll ==> 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245030/how-to-restrict-the-use-of-certain-cryptographic-algorithms-and-protoc
TLS/SSL Settings ==> 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786418(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_SchannelTR_TLS10

Comment: you've found the important links. Once you've digested the info and configured AD FS and WAP, you need to test the scenarios for the applications federated. Think of the clients that need to talk to AD FS. If just browsers think of the OS and varieties of browsers. If there are apps, test them to ensure they can use TLS 1.2. Disabling TLS 1.0, 1.1 is easy. and AD FS will function. You just need to ensure those that need to talk to AD FS and WAP continue to be able to.

Answer (score 3):

This is at a lower layer than ADFS so nothing to do ADFS wise.

Just FYI: I find https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ useful which shows the current settings.

Also download "IIS Crypto" and have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is to use the free IISCrypto tool.  It allows you to change many protocols and ciphers easily with just a few clicks, including TLS.  Just remember to backup before making changes and then restart after you use it so that the registry changes take effect.

https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto